# Retrieve at least certain amount of records from mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the best way of telling mySQL to fetch a minimum number of records?

Say I have a products table, and I need to return at LEAST 5 items to fit the website design.
I could easily write something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE featured = true;
```

But if this returned only 3 results, what would be the best way to return an additional 2 products from the DB? I was thinking perhaps a `UNION` join with a query to return a couple of random products. Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: In the absence of further information, a UNION is a good way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ORDER BY + LIMIT to achieve that effect:

Given that dataset:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM P;
+--------+----------+
| name   | featured |
+--------+----------+
| Apple  |        1 |
| Pear   |        1 |
| Orange |        1 |
| Lime   |        0 |
| Turnip |        0 |
| Salad  |        0 |
+--------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you see, not enough "featured" products:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM P WHERE featured = true LIMIT 5;
+--------+----------+
| name   | featured |
+--------+----------+
| Apple  |        1 |
| Pear   |        1 |
| Orange |        1 |
+--------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 se
```

But by ordering to retrieve *first* featured, then complete up to the limit with *non featured* product, you have what you want:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM P ORDER BY featured DESC LIMIT 5;
+--------+----------+
| name   | featured |
+--------+----------+
| Apple  |        1 |
| Pear   |        1 |
| Orange |        1 |
| Lime   |        0 |
| Turnip |        0 |
+--------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```